# Adding Custom Attributes to SimpleSAMLPhp

Tags: saml-2.0, simplesamlphp

I'm using this page as a reference guide: [core:PHP](http://simplesamlphp.org/docs/trunk/core%3aauthproc_php)

It reads as applying to attributes that already exist in my LDAP, but what if I wanted to add a new attribute entirely?

I added the following two new ones; the first is being renamed to something new, and the second one is static:

```
saml20-idp-hosted.php
_____________________
   100 => array(
    'class' => 'core:PHP',
    'code' => '
        if (!empty($attributes["blahblahID"])) {
              $employeeID = $attributes["blahblahID"][0];
              $attributes["employeeID"] = array($employeeID);
        }
        $attributes["securityKey"] = array("123456");
        if (!empty($attributes["displayname"])) {
              $displayname = $attributes["displayname"][0];
              $attributes["UserName"] = array($displayname);
        }
    ',
),

saml20-sp-remote.php
____________________
$metadata['Corestream'] = array(
    'metadata-set' => 'saml20-sp-remote',
    'simplesaml.attributes'      => true,
    'attributes' => array('UserName','employeeID','securityKey'),
.........
```

Will the employeeID and securityKey attributes automatically pass to the SP in this way?

EDIT:

I was able to run a test and am getting an error from the SP that the attribute UserName does not exist. What did I do incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be better off using [core:AttributeMap](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/core%3aauthproc_attributemap) and [core:AttributeAdd](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/core%3aauthproc_attributeadd) for this.  Usage of the core:PHP module is generally not recommended, due to PHP recommending [against](http://php.net/eval#44008) these kinds of constructions.  If you really need something that is not offered by the included [AuthProc](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-authproc) filters, consider writing your own.

Comment: Somehow I never saw AttributeAdd until you posted about it. Thanks!